# Pyinstaller Onefile frozendict temp _MEI FILENOTFOUNDERROR

Tags: python, anaconda, pyinstaller, yfinance

I have a script that uses the yfinance package from conda-forge. It pulls in some information from that package on certain stocks and then will copy said information to the clipboard so it can be quickly pasted into an text based doc. The script runs from my Pycharm IDE with zero issues but as soon as I use Pyinstaller to package it up into one file I run into a FileNotFoundError. Here is the traceback I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pw_news_aggregator.py", line 2, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 499, in exec_module
  File "yfinance\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 499, in exec_module
  File "yfinance\ticker.py", line 29, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 499, in exec_module
  File "yfinance\base.py", line 32, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 499, in exec_module
  File "yfinance\data.py", line 18, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 499, in exec_module
  File "frozendict\__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\USER~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI151882\\frozendict\\VERSION'
[27792] Failed to execute script 'pw_news_aggregator' due to unhandled exception!
```

My Pyinstaller powershell command is: pyinstaller --onefile --name  
Very basic and it has worked with zero issues in the past.

Here is my .spec file too:

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-


block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(
    ['C:\\Users\\USER\\Coding\\Projects\\Portfolio_Watch\\pw_news_aggregator.py'],
    pathex=[],
    binaries=[],
    datas=[],
    hiddenimports=[],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
    win_private_assemblies=False,
    cipher=block_cipher,
    noarchive=False,
)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data, cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    a.binaries,
    a.zipfiles,
    a.datas,
    [],
    name='PW News Aggregator',
    debug=False,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    runtime_tmpdir=None,
    console=True,
    disable_windowed_traceback=False,
    argv_emulation=False,
    target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None,
    entitlements_file=None,
)
```

I tried to make a new conda env thinking it was maybe corrupted. But the same error occurs every time. I am at a loss as to why the frozendict is causing any issues, it is installed seemingly.

Also, in the traceback, the C path contains an incorrect user name. I'm not sure if that is a redaction done by Pyinstaller or what. It is: 'C:\Users\FirstNameLastInitial~1...' while it should be 'C:\Users\FirstNameLastName...'

Any ideas are much appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

this is because `frozendict` module reads a static file `VERSION` in `__init__.py` when importing. However PyInstaller only analyze script file dependency chain but cannot recognize static file dependency.

it's quite hard because we are not easy to add static file from site-packages in PyInstaller. (the site-packages folder is different from the project folder, make it harder to describe a related path in spec file and also bind this file with other frozendict project file as well).

after some testing, i add this code, can be considered as a patch, at the very top of the main Python file, which will resolve it.

```py
import sys

if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    # because PyInstaller will NOT pack non-python text file into binary (in site-packages/frozendict/VERSION)
    # after packing, it will cause a FileNotFoundError since frozendict.__init__ visits this file
    # we generate it dynamically before importing frozendict to resolve this issue
    with open(sys._MEIPASS + "/frozendict/VERSION", "w") as f:
        f.write("2.3.1")
```

in binary code, the VERSOIN file will be generated dynamically after the script starts and BEFORE the `frozendict` is imported, to make `frozendict.__init__` able to find the `VERSION` file.

Answer (score 0):

I've struggled with this issue for a long time and maybe this can help anyone.

For a long time, when I compiled my exe file I added an extra part to the string. I used this command line:

```
pyinstaller --collect-data frozendict --onefile -w FileName.py
```

where `--collect-data frozendict` would solve the error that the exe file showed when executing it (Error: "No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI177122\frozendict\VERSION'").

The solution now that have worked for me was to uninstall the frozendict library and then reinstall to the latest version (as of 2023-12-28: version 2.3.10). Now I don' need the extra part in my command line and the missing folder appears again in my temp folder.